# Powering amplifier from battery or 230V power supply with automatic switch

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I'm trying to figure out the best way to power my amplifier using either a battery OR a 230V power supply.

The amplifier has a wide input range that'll happily take the ~12V from the battery or the 24V from the power supply, but i'm not really sure about the best way to handle all of it.

What i want is for the power supply to take priority whenever it has power, so that the battery is only used when there's no mains power.
Additionally i also have a battery charger that i want to keep the battery topped up when the amp is running on mains power and battery isn't used.

How do i isolate and switch everything properly? Obviously i would like to waste as little power on the whole isolation/switching as possible to save battery power.

Do i just litter the circuit with relays to switch everything?

My devices is the following:
J1: 230VAC input jack
PS1: 230VAC to 24VDC power supply for the amp
PS2: Battery charger for the battery

[image]

Comment: Diode from battery and diode from supply to load. Highest voltage wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMT6VI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A 230 V AC relay detects presence of mains power and switches amplifier supply from battery to mains PSU.*

The relay does not load the battery circuit at all.

Comment: Just to be sure: the reason you have RLY1 twice is just for simplicity in terms of the schematic, right?

Comment: No, it's for clarity rather than use the relay symbol and a rat's nest of wiring. It's the same device. The coil is on the left. The contact operated by the coil is on the right.

Comment: Yeah. That's the question i was trying to purvey. But we got there :)

Comment: Good. Wait a while to encourage other useful answers and then accept the best one to indicate that your question is answered.

Comment: The amp should be off when turning on AC to avoid contact wear from additional surge current on contact unless rated for this. Ic= CdV/dt or \$\Delta V/ESR\$ also a DPST may be better to isolate CM SMPS charger noise on the common Bat-